# Segue is blank (black) , can't view the data

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue

```
(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DetailPlacePage"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.Allplace indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NomadPlaceDetailViewController *placedetailcontroller = segue.destinationViewController;
    placedetailcontroller.myDictionary = [self.placeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  }
}
```

This is the code I use to prepare segue for UIviewcontroller. 
Can't see the next view controller , screen gets blank and just navigation bar is shown .

Comment: There isn't enough here to help us. Have you actually set a breakpoint and tried stepping into the code?

Comment: This method doesn't push to another view.. this method is used to preform actions with a segue is triggered. Are your view controllers linked together through a modal or push?

Answer (score -1):

Try casting your NomadPlaceDetailViewController:

```
NomadPlaceDetailViewController *placedetailcontroller = (NomadPlaceDetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
```

Comment: Objective-C is a dynamic language. A cast is useful for preventing an compiler warning, but as long as the class handles the messages that it is being sent it's unlikely to be the problem.